# Error (qt5_add_resources) when build kaffeine in debian jessie

Tags: debian, compiling, qt

in Kaffeine <1.3 is bug with samba, I try to build version 1.3.x. But after call cmake, I get an error:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (qt5_add_resources):
  **Unknown CMake command "qt5_add_resources".**
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I test version and settings:

```
$ qtchooser -print-env
QT_SELECT="default"
QTTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin"
QTLIBDIR="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"

$ qmake -v
QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.3.2 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

$ cmake --version
cmake version 3.0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing a necessary qt package. Try installing the **qt5-default** package.

```
sudo apt-get install -y qt5-default
```

Comment: I check qt5-default, but it is already installed.